# TreeView from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012

I have a database table (named PatientDetails) which includes below columns :

```
PatientId not null,
title,
sex,
lastname,
birthday,
firstname,
middlename,
remarkline,
remarks
```

and by using above table, I want `PatientId` as `Parent` and childnode as `firstname` a `TreeView` in c#. How can I do that ?

I have made some codebehind as below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = RunQuery("select PatientId,firstname from PatientDetails");

    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        TreeNode root = new TreeNode(
            ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString(),
            ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());

        root.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Expand;
        CreateNode(root);
        TVPatArc.Nodes.Add(root);
    }      
}

void CreateNode(TreeNode node)
{
    DataSet ds = RunQuery("Select PatientId,firstname "
                          + "from PatientDetails where PatientId ="
                          + node.Value);

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        TreeNode tnode = new TreeNode(
            ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString(),
            ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());

        tnode.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Expand;
        node.ChildNodes.Add(tnode);
        CreateNode(tnode);
    }
}

DataSet RunQuery(String Query)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    String connStr = "Data Source=LOCALHOST\\SQLEXPRESS;"
                     + "Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;"
                     + "User ID=sa;Password=sa";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand(Query, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(objCommand);
        da.Fill(ds);
        da.Dispose();
    }

    return ds;
}
```

But line `CreateNode(tnode);` it gives the `System.StackOverflowException`. I think it is due to infinite loop. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you need to hit DB multiple times? if you are constructing Parent and Child from Same Record?

On page load try like this

```
DataSet ds = RunQuery("select PatientId,firstname from PatientDetails");

for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
TreeNode root = new TreeNode(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ID"].ToString(), ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ID"].ToString());
root.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Expand;
TreeNode child = new TreeNode(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ID"].ToString(), ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["FirstName"].ToString());
root.ChildNodes.Add(child);
TVPatArc.Nodes.Add(root);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot it working....now i wanna make that if i click on patient firstname then it should be redirect to another page...How can i do?

Comment: There is a Property on treenode called "NavigateUrl", you can assign a URL to that property. For example you assign "~/PatientDetail.aspx?id={idOfPatient}"

Comment: i have try with the propery. but when i click on the firstname which child then tree is again generate same as 2 time....so could you please let me step by step how to navigateurl. Thanks

Comment: Check IsPostBack, When the page is posted dont do the tree building logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look into your query, you're retrieving the same patient ad infinitum:

RunQuery("Select PatientId,firstname from PatientDetails where PatientId =" + node.Value);

I suggest to change the query to retrieve patients by its parent, if the field in database is ParentPatientId then use:

RunQuery("Select PatientId,firstname from PatientDetails where ParentPatientId =" + node.Value);

By the way, this is very inefficient, because you'll launch at least one query per patient, if you've a million of patients then you're launching at least one million queries. It's better to retrieve all in one single query, ordered by ParentPatientId, and then build the tree from the result. If you're using Oracle, you have also DML commands to help you building trees (CONNECT BY and START WITH).

Comment: I have field name as PatientId not as ParentPatientId....so i think it not problem with query

Comment: Then you don't need using recursion, you can retrieve all your patients and create a node for each one.